# how is advaita deep sleep blankness different from materialist nothingness?

Tags: advaita, vedanta

i was convinced by the advaita point of view actually ia am still........but still a doubt is coming......acc to advaita in deep sleep or coma the blankness we expeirience is actually conciousness devoid of objects...... actually my doubt is even a random materialist or atheist also says the same the after death there is nothing sor of dark and even advaita also says the same....is this some sort of mental gymnastic to solve fear of death or somethin.....are materialist true and advaita wrong? how can we know for sure??

Comment: No. The difference is - Advaitins say - the atman experiences blankness during deep sleep, whereas materialists say - there is no *atman* or *self* after death, so there is experience, but no self to feel or acknowledge it.